# C# delegate dictionary add

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to create a method like this:

```
private static void AddOrAppend<K>(this Dictionary<K, MulticastDelegate> firstList, K key, MulticastDelegate newFunc)
{
    if (!firstList.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        firstList.Add(key, newFunc);
    }
    else
    {
        firstList[key] += newFunc;  // this line fails
    }
}
```

But this fails because it says you can't add multicast delegates. Is there something I'm missing? I thought the delegate keyword was just shorthand for a class which inherits from MulticastDelegate.

Comment: Or you could use `ConcurrentDictionary` in .NET 4.0...

Comment: @Steven - I'm not sure how that addresses the problem?

Comment: @Marc: It's not a solution to the problem, it's a way to avoid it entirely by not reinventing that wheel.  Specifically, the sort of functionality he's trying to create is already available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675.aspx

Comment: @Steven - interesting; not a method I've bumped into recently ;p

Comment: It came up on SO, of all places.  Someone was asking how atomic the delegate call was.  Turns out that the delegate may get called more than once, if there's a race condition.  (Sorry I can't find the link.)

Comment: @Marc: Sorry, forgot to say your name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
firstList[key] = (MulticastDelegate)Delegate.Combine(firstList[key],newFunc);
```

with test:

```
        var data = new Dictionary<int, MulticastDelegate>();

        Action action1 = () => Console.WriteLine("abc");
        Action action2 = () => Console.WriteLine("def");
        data.AddOrAppend(1, action1);
        data.AddOrAppend(1, action2);
        data[1].DynamicInvoke();
```

(which works)

But tbh, Just use `Delegate` in place of `MulticastDelegate`; this is largely a hangover from something that never really worked. Or better; a specific *type* of delegate (perhaps `Action`).

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question, but do you know why my code didn't work?